# Github: display the wiki home on a repository front page

Tags: github, wiki

I recently created a global wiki for my company in a Github repo. It's an empty repository which I created just to use its wiki.

My problem: on the front page of this wiki repo, the Readme is displayed. And this Readme is empty, except for a link to the wiki's home.

I want to display this home on the front page of the repo. Is it possible?

Comment: On a related note, I have been searching for a while to customize repository front pages but found nothing simple.  In my specific case, I would like to see the README, but not the "code" listing (i.e. the files and directories of the project).  The "code listing" should only show once one clicks on "Code".  Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is better to use https://pages.github.com/ you could even go further and use [hugo](https://gohugo.io/), in long term could be easy to maintain since you just keep track of all your articles/posts within a repo.

Regarding your question probably a redirect from the main repo to the wiki may work, check the docs for more info: https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/

With a redirect, I mean that you will need to have an index.html redirecting to the wiki URL.

Comment: so basically, you're telling me that it's not possible. I don't intend to create a specific set of github pages for this wiki. It's working, it's just not convenient. Thanks anyway.